# Teensy usb keyboard + Android

Tags: android, keyboard, teensy

I've just gotten one of these Teensy boards: http://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy_pins.html

I am trying to set it up using the basic keyboards tutorial. It is working correctly on Windows PC devices when I plug it in and press one of my buttons the proper key presses come through. But if I plug it into an Android device (Toshiba Thrive) I can tell that it recognizes it as a keyboard because it stops showing me the soft keyboard just as it does if I plug in a usb keyboard. But when I press my buttons no keypresses come through.

Does anyone have experience setting up a teensy board to be recognized as a USB keyboard on Android?

Edit so it turns out that it works if I select USB type "Disk(internal) + Keyboard"
But not with "Keyboard + Mouse + Joystick" I now suspect that the inclusion of joystick in this profile is what is causing it not to work. I've read that some android devices do not support input devices with joysticks.

So a followup question would be: Does anyone know how to remove the joystick functionality from the Teensy 2.0 board?

Comment: It's probably more the declaration of the functionality you need to remove from the firmware than the functionality itself, so maybe look at the descriptors and similar configuration.  Curious why two people want this question closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not figure out how to do it from teensyduino (aside from having it also be recognized as storage in addition to keyboard). But I did find out that if you skip the teensyduino and just edit C files and compile them, then manually load the hex file to the board it work just fine as a keyboard on android and PC.

Here is the page I used most to get it set up: http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_keyboard.html

I'd still be very interested if any one knows how it can be set up so that it will work from teensyduino.